# How to show one ACF field on all pages

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Right now one this certain ACF is only displayed on the user end of the relevant page where generated ACF editor appears.

What I want to do is make a 'global' ACF, featured in certain php include that will appear on most of the pages in my template.

How do I achieve this?

The only way I can achieve this effect is disregard my include, recode each page where I want that global ACF to appear, and then make sure ACF editor appears on each page in wp-admin, which isn't very graceful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue too. If you still need a solution (or for those who still need an answer) ACF have released a premium add-on called "Options" [ACF Options](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/options-page/).

This will allow global use of custom fields. Check out the video tutorial on the page to customize the sidemenu for grouped global content.

`<?php the_field('field_name', 'option'); ?>` will call the content of that particular field.

I hope this helps.